# Use IN statement on alphanumeric string variable

Tags: sas

I need to make a query and therein to use the `IN` statement.

First I read in a txt file:

```
filename ticklist '/home/mypath/myfile.txt';
data sp500;
     infile ticklist;
     input smbl $;
     smbl=upcase(smbl);
run;
```

This gives me the variable `sp500.smbl` with values `AA, HNZ, ...` (over 500).

Then I make a query:

```
data result;
     set mydata;
     where also company_symbol IN (sp500.smbl);
run;
```

I always get the well-known issue:

> Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, -.

How is it possible to use an alphanumeric variable with the `IN`statement? And why does it not work with it - are alphanumeric strings not quoted? What kind of data structure is needed in the `IN`statement?

Comment: There datastep `where` statement isn't this powerful.  But if you set up a query in `proc sql`, the `where` clause will do pretty much what you want.

Comment: @user2161151 You mean like `where company_symbol = sp500.smbl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use proc sql to do this.  You may want to add trim and compress to company_symbol to make sure whitespace doesn't break any match between company_symbol and smbl

This will select all the fields from mydata where company_symbol matches smbl in the table sp500

```
proc sql noprint;

    create table result as
    select *
    from mydata
    where company_symbol in (select distinct smbl from sp500)
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It runs perfectly! Do you know, why the `IN`statement cannot be used on an alphanumeric string variable as shown in my example code? I would like to understand better how SAS works.

Comment: I would suggest reading more of the documentation because there are a lot of things that are explained well there.  [Here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jd70cudhsnogn1d6kr8j43n6bu.html) is a link to documentation on where processing that can tell you much more than i could in a comment

Comment: The link does it as well. I haven't found something when googeling around searching for `SAS IN alphanumeric string`. Thanks!

Comment: You can use that form with a list, but you cannot access another table through a data step unless you do a merge by company_symbol and keep only that variable in sp500 or create a macro variable containing the list-- you cannot subquery another table in a data step-- its way easier to compare a field to a variable from another table with proc sql

Comment: @scott Actually not true at all, there are a bunch of (esoteric) ways of querying a table directly.  You can use direct access with [open](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0q72zlfmfjplon1p3nprf85sdin.htm), you can use `_point_` to iterate through, or a hash table (which is the only one I find actually useful), as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scott's answer is definitely a good one, but here are a few alternatives.

First off, the closest way to what you actually wrote, would be to enclose the terms in quotes, select them into a macro variable, and then use them in the data step:

```
proc sql;
 select quote(smbl) into :smbllist separated by ' '
 from sp500;
quit;

data result;
set mydata;
where company_symbol in (&smbllist.);
run;
```

This isn't a particularly good way to do this, but it works.

Alternatives:

Data step merge (or SQL Join) is usually better than an in comparison, as it takes better advantage of hash/index/etc.

```
data result;
merge mydata(in=a) sp500(in=sp);
by company_symbol;
if a and sp;
run;
```

This requires them to be sorted, and the same variable name in both (you can use RENAME on one of the data sets in the merge statement if needed).  SQL inner join would do the same thing, and bonus not require explicit sorting, though it might sort the data for you without telling you (thus not saving time).  Depends on if a hash solution would work or not (if so, then it doesn't have to sort).

---

Formats often are faster if sorting is an extra step for you (ie, if it's not normally sorted this way).

data for_fmts;
set sp500;
fmtname='$SMBLF';
start=smbl;
label="1"; *or whatever you want for TRUE;
output;
if *n*=1 then do;
hlo='o'; *this checks for nonmatches;
start=' ';
label='0'; *or whatever you want for FALSE;
output;
end;
run;

*has to be NODUPKEY by smbl, so if there are duplicates, do a proc sort nodupkey;

proc format cntlin=for_fmts;
quit;

data result;
set mydata;
where put(company_symbol,$SMBLF.)='1';
run;

---

Hash table is the closest to what you actually wrote in terms of object-oriented thinking.

```
data result;
if _n_=1 then do;
if 0 then set sp500;
declare hash sp('dataset:sp500');
sp.defineKey('smbl');
sp.defineData('smbl'); *or whatever you want to return when found, if something;
sp.defineDone();
call missing (smbl); *initialize to missing to avoid warning;
end;
set mydata;
rc = sp.find(key:company_symbol);
if rc eq 0 then output; *or you could do this in one statement, skipping the rc, just being clear here;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Joe - you mention that joins can take better advantage of indexes compared to an `in` statement.  Do you know where I can read up on this?

Comment: Using `IN` with a long string of values (ie, thousands or something) evaluates to a bunch of `OR` statements, which can be a really bad idea with a lot of them.  The index on the main table is used of course, but since there isn't an index on the values, you often don't get as good of performance as a JOIN would.  This (as with all SQL) is highly subject to the optimizer, of course, and who knows what could happen.  An `IN` with a select statement (ie, `WHERE X IN (select X from othertable)`) often will resolve to a `JOIN`, but not always.

Comment: Ahh ok, I misunderstood. I was thinking of a query such as `select * from table where id in (select id from table2)`.  Thanks for the clarification.